# What are the Parameters of Datagrid in Microsoft Fluent UI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm using the Microsoft Fluent UI library for Blazor. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is display data using the Datagrid component which is ***FluentDataGrid*** from ***Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI*** package.

I couldn't find any documentation about the type of parameters for this component. So what do these parameters do? And what data type should I pass in.

- TItem
- RowsData
- ColumnDefinitions
- GenerateHeader

Comment: Did you look at the source?  There is an extensive "/DatagridPage".

Comment: Which source? I tried Microsoft documentation and it didn't help me much. Can you send the link you are talking about?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/fast-blazor